# What is the best practice to include CSS and Scripts in php?

Tags: php

I've read this: [PHP & CSS - Should I Link or Include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836663/php-css-should-i-link-or-include) 
and this: [What is the best practice to include header and footer in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413749/what-is-the-best-practice-to-include-header-and-footer-in-php) 
and also this: [Creating a PHP header/footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054638/creating-a-php-header-footer)

Nice pieces of information there, but my question is different.
I am including header and footer no problem. Sometimes I face this issue:

Different pages with different data and different scripts required, specifically Ajax. I separate my Ajax post requests with different files to include it only on its page. Of course if I have all the `<link>` and `<script>` in `header.php` and `footer.php` they will be included everywhere, so thats useless code being rendered.

Someone in Stackoverflow once told me that it's not a good practice to write an if condition  to run scripts based on a page.

So what is the best practices for this?

**P.S.**

Kindly don't be harsh on me if this question might be so simple, being a self taught developer makes me miss lots of "might be basic" things since I don't have a person to guide me. Appreciate it.

Comment: Have you messed around with the locations of the css? ie. `<link href="../css.css">`, `<link href="/css.css">`, `<link href="css.css">`, etc

Comment: My team uses `/assets` or `/resources` and all links always uses items in there.

Comment: As for your second question, that's for you and your template system to work out. Get some inspiration from Twig's named blocks for example: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#template-inheritance